# Docker/PostgreSQL creating server using pgadmin4 and having a user problem

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

After some problems i removed the postgres container and pgadmin and recreate them and after it i try to create a server and the error was shown to me FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres".

I saw some things here in the stackoverflow, but none of them can be applied to my problem, at least i guess not.

I was seeking how to use `docker exec` to try to execute a command in the container and i'm still seeing how to use this command, but having no idea how to use for my problem.

I'm using ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

So i find the solution for my problem and i'll explain it here for those who are facing the same problem.

Use the following commands
`docker exec -it here_you_put_container_name psql -U postgres`

Now just use this command

`create user postgres with superuser password 'postgres';`
and use \q after it to leave

You can switch the user and the password.
Now you can create a server in the pgadmin and be happy :)